# Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object. PHP Version differs?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well, this code works perfectly fine localhost with PHP 5.6.15, but on my web server that uses PHP 5.5.30, it gives me that error on line 19.

```
<?php
//Classe usada para enviar informações do banco de dados ou do servidor SRCDS.
class sendInfo{

  //Função usada para arrumar os tempos irregulares de determinado mapa no banco de dados do ckSurf.
  function fixMapRecords($map, $steamid){
    try {
      $db = dbConnection::getConnection();
      //Pega o tempo do usuário chave.
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT runtimepro FROM ck_playertimes WHERE mapname=:targetmap AND steamid=:targetsteamid;");
      $stmt->bindValue(':targetmap', $map, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindValue(':targetsteamid', $steamid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      //Remove todo tempo que é menor do que o do usuário chave.
      foreach ($result as $pro) {
        $protime = $pro['runtimepro'] - 0.0001;
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM ck_playertimes WHERE mapname =:targetmap AND runtimepro<:targettime");
        $stmt2->bindValue(':targetmap', $map, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':targettime', $protime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $result2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
      //Deu tudo certo e os tempos foram removidos, redirecione para a página de sucesso.
      header('Location: ../../messages/success.php');
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
      //Ocorreu algo de errado, redirecione para a página de erro.
      header('Location: ../../messages/error.php');
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This is my database connection class:

```
class dbConnection{
    protected static $db;

    private function __construct() {
      try {
        self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.'; dbname='.DB_DATABASE.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        header('Location: messages/error.php');
      }
    }

    public static function getConnection() {
      if (!self::$db) {
        new dbConnection();
      }
      return self::$db;
    }
  }
```

So I've been trying to find what is the problem for the last 3 hours, absolutely no idea whatsoever.

*I've tried to see any of the exceptions, but it just dies on line 19 of the first code block, so no messages.

**Emulate prepared statement on the second code block was for some reason not letting me read exceptions, removed that and could praise the sun.

Comment: I don't see anything offhand that looks like it shouldn't work in 5.5. I could be missing something, but is it possible there are actually differences in your production database? That would make the prepare return a non-object.

Comment: I actually exported the exact same table from my production database and made the exact same mysql version + engine to test the problem, and it worked flawlessly only on localhost. The only thing different is the PHP version, which I don't want to switch because I have other apps that break when used with 5.6.

Comment: You're catching the exception... why not read the message?  Almost 100% certain it would be a database issue, not PHP.

Comment: Do you have error handling for PDO set to exceptions?  `If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).`  Otherwise, you'd have to check if `$stmt2` is false and get the error through other means.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - also no idea what the class looks like, and how you're using all this and what your column types are. check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I forgot to give DELETE permission to my database user, issue fixed.

Comment: And that is why your script needs more error handling.